# Node / Nodist and Jade.cmd

Tags: node.js, pug, webstorm

I am following the MEAN stack series on PluralSight. I have reached a stage where I need to add a File Watcher in WebStorm 8 to Jade files.

The author in the video has the following path for his watcher program:

c:/nodist/bin/jade.cmd:

[image: file watcher dialog]

I cannot do the same as him because I do not have that directory! I have downloaded and extracted `nodist` but all I see is a bunch of files (node.exe being among them, even though I had node.js installed before).

Plus, in the `/bin/` folder in the extracted nodist zip there is no `jade.cmd`!

How can I get the `jade.cmd` into the bin folder for nodist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install Jade using npm, like

```
npm install jade -g
```

jade.cmd will be created in your home directory, like

```
C:\Users\your.name\AppData\Roaming\npm\jade.cmd
```

and then specify this full path in the Jade file watcher

Comment: Thank you that worked! I did it through the `Node.js command prompt`